# Can an Indian Tourist eVisa be used for Business

Tags: visas, india, e-visas

I got a 180 day multi-entry Tourist eVisa via iVisa one month ago. Can I use this visa for business as well?

Comment: What do its conditions say? Do you need the [India Business Visa](https://www.evisaindia.org/types/business-visa/)? [This page](https://www.tripsavvy.com/guide-to-indian-visa-types-1539766) says of the tourist visa: "The scope of visas under the program has also been widened to include short-term medical treatment and yoga courses, and casual business visits and conferences. Previously, these required separate medical/student/business visas." But you need to read its actual conditions.